# TypeScript cannot find module with non-relative path 'src/xxx'

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I had meet the problem that resolve non-relative moduels in typescript. And try `baseUrl`, `paths` and so on, but it not works....

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
 }
}
```

The project dirs:

```
root
  ├─src
    ├── APIs
    ├── config
    ├── constants
    ├── middlewares
    ├── models
    ├── routes
    ├── services
          - foo.ts   
    ├── utils
    └── app.ts
```

in **app.ts**

```
import foo from 'src/services/foo'
```

And run with `ts-node src/app.ts`.

But the error occurs:

```
Cannot find module 'src/services/foo'
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I add `paths` option to resolve it.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["./src/@types", "./node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

In **app.ts**:

```
import foo from '@/services/foo'
```

Comment: Not a really nice solution. Should work without the '@/'

Comment: I think you are better to define it as `"@src/*": ["src/*"]` so can use the more distinguisable `import foo from '@src/services/foo'`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add [tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) and [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) to *package.json* like this:

```json
    "_moduleDirectories:" ["src"]
```

And in *app.ts* use:

```
    import 'module-alias/register';
```

You will also need to create *tsconfig-path.js* file in your root directory that should look like this:

```js
const tsConfigPaths = require('tsconfig-paths');
const tsConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
tsConfigPaths.register({
    baseUrl: tsConfig.compilerOptions.outDir,
    paths: tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths,
});
```

Also change *tsconfig.json*:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src",
        "paths": {
            "*":["./*"]
        }
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `tsconfig-paths` and add the following in `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"ts-node": {
    // Do not forget to `npm i -D tsconfig-paths`
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
```

Ref: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#paths-and-baseurl